# Is there a pandas function to get the mean of a given range of cells?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reducing the noise in a pointcloud dataset from a multibeamscan, the dataset i am currently working on has 87295 rows.
I want to get the mean (or standard deviation) of a range of cells. Each range of cells is 1% of the entire dataframe.

It's been awhile since I've used Python/Pandas, but this is what I've come up with

```
amount_of_rows = df['X'].count()
percentage = 0.01 
row1 = int(amount_of_rows * percentage) 
row2 = int(amount_of_rows * (percentage * 2))
row3 = int(amount_of_rows * (percentage * 3))
row4...
row5....
```

This goes on for 100 rows.

```
row1 = 872
row2 = 1745
```

So then I would use these rows to get the average between them like so.

```
rowmean1 = df[row1:row2].mean()
rowmean2 = df[row2:row3].mean()
rowmean3 = df[row3:row4].mean()
rowmean4...
rowmean5...
```

I would then use these `rowmeans` to filter the data based on the value, in the same range.
So `rowmean1` is the mean of all the values between `872` and `1745`

But before I do that, I would like to know if there is a better way to do it? Without copypasting my code 100 times? I've tried writing different functions and loops to do so myself, but nothing yielded the desired result.

sample df

```
          X          Y     Z

1   100980.05  498385.17 -9.15
2   100980.08  498385.13 -9.14
3   100980.11  498385.08 -9.13
4   100980.13  498385.04 -9.12
5   100980.16  498384.99 -9.11
6   100980.19  498384.95 -9.10
7   100980.26  498384.84 -8.56
8   100980.24  498384.86 -9.08
9   100980.28  498384.79 -8.86
10  100980.30  498384.77 -9.06
11  100980.32  498384.73 -9.05
12  100980.35  498384.68 -9.04
13  100980.38  498384.64 -9.03
14  100980.40  498384.59 -9.02
15  100980.43  498384.55 -9.01
16  100980.46  498384.51 -8.99
17  100980.48  498384.47 -8.98
18  100980.51  498384.42 -8.97
19  100980.54  498384.38 -8.96
20  100980.56  498384.34 -8.95
21  100980.59  498384.29 -8.94
22  100980.62  498384.25 -8.92
23  100980.64  498384.21 -8.91
24  100980.67  498384.17 -8.90
25  100980.69  498384.12 -8.89
26  100980.73  498384.07 -8.58
27  100980.75  498384.04 -8.87
28  100980.77  498384.00 -8.86
29  100980.80  498383.96 -8.85
30  100980.82  498383.91 -8.84
```

Comment: isn't it df.loc[index1:index2].mean() ?

Comment: @tgrandje what do you mean?(haha) that I should use df.iloc?

Comment: No, I meant df[x] is a way to capture columns, not rows (?)

Comment: @tgrandje I get it, the `df['X'].count` part is so that i get a single value, cause if i use df.count i get counts for all the columns. Which are the same for all of them

Comment: `pandas.rolling.mean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df["percentage"] = 1/len(df)
df['cum'] = df['percentage'].cumsum()

for val in np.arange(0.01, 1.01, .01):
  precedent = val - .01
  ix = df[(precedent < df['cum']) & (df['cum'] <= val)].index
  this_mean = df.loc[ix, 'X'].mean()
  print(min(ix), '->', max(ix), ':', this_mean)
```

Comment: Thanks! looks promising, ill take a look at it tomorrow :)

Comment: so when I use this i get an index error. Also when i just print `rows` i only get one number repeating the entire time

Comment: can you post a sample of your original dataframe ? (something like df.head().to_dict())

Comment: There was a typo about the counter in the list comprehension, sorry about that

Comment: i got the first 30 rows

Comment: i saw the amout_of_rows typo, which one are you talking about?

Comment: Woops, didn't see THAT one... No, I was talking about the "k" I just replaced by an "x"

Comment: Owh yeah with the typo fixed it actually goes up. Lemme see if i can work something out now :)

Comment: So i get an Indexerror: List index out of range on the `rowmeans`. I think this is, cause it doesn't stop? And looks for a `df.loc` that doesn't exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224792/discussion-between-tgrandje-and-martijn-van-amsterdam).